# Can JNI callback function use the class member?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I want to use class member "tvLog" in function PrintLog() which will be called in JNI in C++. But it caused the "Shutting down VM.... FATAL EXCEPTION: main...." error. Could anyone tell me why?

simple_test.java:

```
public class simple_test extends Activity {
    private TextView tvLog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LogTextView);

    public int PrintLog(int i) {
        tvLog.setText("Log from JNI");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

demo_jni.cpp

```
...
mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "PrintLog", "(I)I");
...
int ret = env->CallIntMethod(obj, mid, 1);
...
```

main.xml:

```
<TextView android:text="" android:layout_x="14dp" android:layout_y="147dp" android:layout_width="290dp" android:layout_height="98dp" android:id="@+id/LogTextView"></TextView>
```

Comment: The full stack trace, would be helpful.

Comment: how do you obtain the cls object?

Answer (score 0):

`private TextView tvLog` ==>
`static private TextView tvLog`